# Fluent Nhibernate will not save

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following classes:

```
public class PhoneModel
{
     public virtual ModelIdentifier SupportModels
}
public class ModelIdentifier
{
     public virtual string Name
     public virtual IList<string> Values
}
```

This is how i mapped it:

```
      mapping.Component(x => x.SuppoertedModel, y =>
      {
        y.Map(x => x.Name, "FAMILY_ID");
        y.HasMany(x => x.Values).Element("VALUE").Table("SUPPORTEDMODULS")
      }
```

2 tables were created:

1. PhoneModel 
       column "FAMILY_ID"
2. SUPPORTEDMODELS
       column "VALUE", "PHONE_MODEL_ID"

The problem is that when I am adding values, it will not save it to the SUPPORTEDMODELS table:

```
var pm = new PhoneModel();
pm.SupportedModels.Name = "11"
pm.SupportedModels.Values.Add("34");
```

Comment: Just to make sense of the question, "SupportModels", "SuppoertedModel", "SUPPORTEDMODULS" and "SUPPORTEDMODELS" are supposed to reference the same table, right?

Comment: Yes, i didn't want to enter the real names :)

Answer (score 0):

- you are missing `HasMany(x => x.Values).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`
- maybe session.Flush() or transaction.Commit() is missing in the test code

btw: if the order of the `Values` is not important then change it to `ICollection<string>` and `HasMany().AsSet()` since this allows NH to optimise some things and code can not rely on the order which is not relyable when using sql.